# Building an indeterminate array of functions to pass to $q.all

Tags: angularjs, q

I'm building an array of functions to pass to $q.all, and I'm wondering if I'm doing it correctly, or if each function will execute separately as I push it into the array.

My code looks like this:

```
function setParallelRequests() {
    var promiseArray = [];
    var counter;

    for (counter; counter < factory.cards.length; counter++) {

        var data = {
            reference: factory.cards[counter].reference
        };

        promiseArray.push(fetchState(data));
    }

    return $q.all(promiseArray)
        .then(function(response){

            return factory.cards;

        }).catch(function(error){
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
}

function fetchState(data) {

    return $http.post('/returnState', data)
       .then(function(response) {

            alert("got the state!");

        })
        .catch(function(error){

            return $q.reject(error);
         });

}
```

Will the code execute as I'm pushing it in the array or will it only execute when $q.all runs?

If it isn't done correctly, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You're not putting functions in the array. You're calling a function (fetchState), which returns a promise, and you put the returned promise to the array.

Comment: So it's fine to do it this way?

Comment: I have no idea of what you want to achieve. Does your code do what you want it to do? If it does, then why wouldn't it be fine? If it doesn't, what would you want it to do instead?

Comment: When the $http service is invoked, it immediately executes an [XHR send operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) and returns a *pending* promise. Any functions given to the `.then` method of that promise are held by the $q service until the promises resolves (either fulfilled or rejected).